# Event Sourcing Aggregate Root User

Tags: c#, events, architecture, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I'm new in event sourcing, and I started a new project to learn about it but I have a couple of questions about architecture.

My first question is about aggregate root. I have a `UserAggregateRoot`. Did this aggregate should contain properties that are typically recognizable to user entities?

I mean my `Aggregate` looks like that

```
public class UserAggregateRoot : AggregateRoot
{
    public Login Login { get; private set; }
    public Password Password { get; private set; }
    public Name Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; private set; }
    public UserId UserId { get; private set; }
    public Status Status { get; private set; }

    private void Apply(UserCreatedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version;
        Login = e.Login;
        Password = e.Password;
        Name = e.Name;
        BirthDate = e.BirthDate;
        Key = e.Key;
    }

    private void Apply(UserActivatedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        Status = e.Status;
        Key = e.Key;
    }

    private void Apply(UserDeletedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        Key = e.Key;
    }

    private void Apply(UserLogedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        Key = e.Key;
    }

    private void Apply(UserUpdatedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        Login = e.Login;
        Password = e.Password;
        Name = e.Name;    
        Key = e.Key;
     }
}
```

Or maybe `UserAggregateRoot` should store user entity looks likes that

```
public class UserAggregateRoot : AggregateRoot
{
    public User User { get; private set; }

    private void Apply(UserCreatedEvent e)
    {
        User = e.User;
        Key = e.User.Key;
    }

    private void Apply(UserActivatedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        User = e.User;
        Key = e.User.Key;
    }

    private void Apply(UserDeletedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        Key = e.User.Key;
        User = e.User;
    }

    private void Apply(UserLogedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        Key = e.User.Key;
    }

    private void Apply(UserUpdatedEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version++;
        User = e.User;
        Key = e.User.Key;
    }
}
```

Second question is if `UserAggregateRoot` stores some orders, should I store the order entity list inside this `UserAggregateRoot`?

What if orders are `AggregateRoot` something like `OrderAggregateRoot`? Should I store `AggregateKey` inside my `UserAggregateRoot` to point this `OrderAggregateRoot`?

Third question is should `Aggregate` root have business logic inside or should business logic be inside entity passed to this `Aggregate` and inside value objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Either way is fine, as I see it
2. Hard to answer without more domain knowledge. Most likely it'd be an `OrderAggregateRoot` with a property that contains the `AggregateKey` of the `UserAggregateRoot`. `OrderAggregateRoot` might even be an entirely different bounded context. If you want more details on defining aggregate roots I suggest looking for defining transactional boundaries.
3. Depends on what you mean by business logic and its specific scope, but Entities and Value Objects can have behaviors of their own.